# Checking multiple files in a directory and return bool value

Tags: php, codeigniter

Checking a single file using the code below works.. but I have to check many files in a loop. I am working on a project that have a lots of files (around 1000). File name differs just on prefix with some breaks. It is a project using CI framework.

> Case I: using is_file() and file_exists()

```
<?php function custom_file_exists($filePath)
   {
         if((is_file($filePath))&&(file_exists($filePath))){
           return 'true';
         }
         return 'false';
   }
?>
```

> Case II: using glob()

```
<?php function custom_file_exists($filePath) {
    $files = glob('uploads/folder/*.pdf', GLOB_BRACE);
    if (in_array($filePath, $files)) {
        return 'true';
    } else {
        return 'false';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the part of the code that I want to work on. File check function works when passing a single filePath but fails when I do the same using following loop.

```
<?php foreach($files as $file):
    //checking all files in loop
    $search = 'uploads/folder/'.$file->name;
    $result = custom_file_exists($search);
    echo $result;  //return 'false' even if the file is present

    //checking for single file
    $search1 = 'uploads/folder/filename';
    $result1 = custom_file_exists($search1);
    echo $result;  //return 'true' when file is present

    endforeach;?>
```

I am not being able to figure out what is wrong with the code. Can someone help me out in this ?? Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks for the help.

> Var dump of glob function as requested.

```
<?php $allfiles = glob("uploads/folder/*.pdf");
print_r($allfiles);?>
```

The result is:

Array ( [0] => uploads/folder/file1.pdf [1] => uploads/folder/file2.pdf  [2] => uploads/folder/file3.pdf [3] => uploads/folder/file4.pdf [4] => uploads/folder/file5.pdf [5] => uploads/folder/file6.pdf [6] => uploads/folder/file7.pdf [7] => uploads/folder/file8.pdf ......

> For the $files that I am using in loop: print_r($files) gives the following output.

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => file1.pdf [description] => something here [published_date] => 2016 [publish] => 1 )

[1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => file2.pdf [description] => something here [published_date] => 2016 [publish] => 1 )

[2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [name] => file3.pdf [description] => something here [published_date] => 2016 [publish] => 1 )

[3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => file4.pdf [description] => something here [published_date] => 2016 [publish] => 1 ) ......

Comment: Have you tried `echo($search)` to verify the file you are intending to search for is actually the one being passed to `custom_file_exists()`?

Comment: yes !! search is the path to file, which is correct !! In spite the fact that file exists, the function is returning false.

Comment: The next step I think then is to `var_dump($files)` for case 2. I've never used the `glob()` function but I'm wondering if it's returning a list of filenames instead of file paths. For example, you're checking if `/uploads/folder/some_file.pdf` exists in the array when the array only contains `some_file.pdf`.

Comment: No, no. Here, the glob function I used, returns all the pdf files within the directory 'uploads/folder/' in the form of file path. like:: array ([0]->'uplodas/folder/file1.pdf' [1]->'uploads/folder/file2.pdf'....);

Comment: I'm not sure you actually tried `echo($search);` If you try that, you most likely see what your problem is. If that still doesn't help, let me know. I will need to see an example of what your `$files` variable contains (`$files` referenced in the last block of code).

Comment: Is the is_file check even necessary? Is there some added security to it over just using file_exists? There are also some permissions quirks referenced in the PHP docs for is_file. [PHP is_file Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

Comment: both is_file() and file_exists() are working with single fixed argument passed as in the case of search1 above. checking on loop is always returning false even when the search sting for both the cases are true !! I updated the question adding the result of print_r($search)... 
checking for single file works but checking all files in loop won't work..